# Insert into table results in "column cannot be null" but said column does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table that when I try to insert a row into it I get

```
Error Code: 1048. Column 'chave_integracao_grupo' cannot be null
```

The table does not have a column named "chave_integracao_grupo".
I tried inserting data into said column but got the standard column does not exist error. I also checked and All the NOT NULL columns are receiving a default expressions.

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE `empresas` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `cnpj` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
   `id_estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `id_cidade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `id_funcionalidade` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
   `inscricao_estadual` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   `razao_social` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `nome_fantasia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `telefone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `cep` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
   `endereco` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `numero` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `id_integracao_gerencial` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK_EMPRESAS_CIDADES` (`id_cidade`),
   KEY `FK_EMPRESAS_ESTADOS` (`id_estado`),
   KEY `FK_EMPRESAS_EMPRESASMATRIZ` (`id_grupo`),
   KEY `FK_EMPRESAS_FUNCIONALIDADES` (`id_funcionalidade`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_EMPRESAS_CIDADES` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cidade`) REFERENCES `cidades` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_EMPRESAS_EMPRESASMATRIZ` FOREIGN KEY (`id_grupo`) REFERENCES `emp_grupo` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_EMPRESAS_ESTADOS` FOREIGN KEY (`id_estado`) REFERENCES `estados` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_EMPRESAS_FUNCIONALIDADES` FOREIGN KEY (`id_funcionalidade`) REFERENCES `emp_funcionalidades` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Does the table have a trigger?

Comment: @HoneyBadger The table does not have any triggers

Comment: Is this by a simple Insert query? Inputting the data manually? Or externally?

Comment: @HoneyBadger it was initially external, but for checking the error I went and did it manually in MySQL Workbench with manually inserted data

Comment: please run `show make table <table_name>`  and `SHOW TRIGGERS FROM <database_name> WHERE table = '<table_name>';`` and copy the output into the question

Comment: Can you show us your table definition?

Comment: Create table edited into the post

Comment: Does the column exist on another table?      
SELECT Table_Name, 
    Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'YOURDBNAMEHERE'
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'chave_integracao_grupo';

Comment: @cking888 I tried that and it returned empty

Comment: something somewhere must have that name. if you haven't already solved this, maybe try SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'YOURDBNAMEHERE' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%chave%';